# preloading audio files

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I want to preload audio files in my website. I am using the following code in html page.

```
<embed src="cheer.swf" hidden="true" autostart=false style="height:0px; width:0px"> 
<embed src="click.swf" hidden="true" autostart=false style="height:0px; width:0px"> 
<embed src="doowip.swf" hidden="true" autostart=false style="height:0px; width:0px">
```

But still all the audio files are played at the beginning of the page. how can i stop the autoplay of audio files.

Also how can i preload the files for ipad safari?

```
<audio id="genclick" src="click.wav" type="audio/wav" >
<audio src="doowip.wav" type="audio/wav" >
<audio src="cheer.wav" type="audio/wav" >
```

the above code not loading the file until i play it from javascript..

```
document.getElementById("genclick").play();
```

where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html the parameter name you're looking for (for the swf 'embed' tags) is 'play', not 'autostart'. Therefore, change them to:

```
<embed src="cheer.swf" hidden="true" play="false" style="height:0px; width:0px" />
```

You could also put them within [object](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) tags and then use:

```
<param name="play" value="false" />
```

I've tested this myself, and it works. As for the  tags for iPad Safari, the HTML5 audio tag has an attribute called 'preload', which when set to 'auto' should preload the files as you want. Try:

```
<audio src="doowip.wav" type="audio/wav" preload="auto" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please read the above comment to TeaTanG's answer. how can i make the audio files stored in ipad safari cache, so that they are played fast and smoothly??

Comment: Is the iPad you're testing on using a 3g connection, as opposed to WiFi? Because according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) documentation, iOS Safari disables the _autoplay_ and _preload_ attributes when using a cellular network... in which case, it looks like in that scenario you're really at the mercy of Apple here.

Comment: I am using a WiFi connection!!

Answer (score 1):

Have not checked though, but can you preload the file doing something like:

```
<EMBED NAME="mySound" SRC="cheer.swf" 
LOOP=FALSE AUTOSTART=FALSE HIDDEN=TRUE style="height:0px; width:0px">
```

Comment: whats the diff?? I dnt find any change, still they are auto played

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML5 audio tag the auto play is a boolean value:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

As for the swf files you should check that the autoplay attribute is not set hardcoded in each of this files.

Comment: I dnt want to autoplay the audio, I want them to be preloaded and cached.. so that I can play them when i want. But wt I observed is, ipad safari is downloading a new copy of the audio file each time 
document.getElementById("genclick").play();
is executed in the same page.